# How to enumerate all the customers on a Skyve instance

Tags: skyve

How can I get a list of the customers that exist on a Skyve instance?

The only idea I've had is to query a table like *ADM_SECURITYUSER* directly:

```sql
SELECT distinct BIZCUSTOMER FROM ADM_SECURITYUSER
```

But I'd prefer to use something from the skyve API if it's available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
org.skyve.metadata.repository.ProvidedRepository.getAllCustomerNames().
```

This interface represents the capabilities required by a metadata repository implementation to be plugged in and used by Skyve (the SPI).
You can cast CORE.getRepository() or an injected org.skyve.metadata.repository.Repository to this interface.

It enumerates the customer names as depicted in the metadata, not in the database.